# jasmine-rails gem used from commandline skips all my specs; why?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine, rake

I'm trying to use `jasmine-rails` gem in my Rails app. It doesn't work in my Rails 4 legacy, so I tried minimal Rails 5 example and got the same problem.

I created new Rails 5 application, installed `jasmine-rails` gem, run `rails generate jasmine_rails:install`. Then I created `spec/javascripts/failure_spec.js` with the following content:

```js
describe('whatever, just give me failure!', function() {
  it('is skipped');
  it('fails', function() {
    expect(3).toBe(1);
    fail("designed failure")
  });
```

});

When I run `rake spec:javascript` it skips both specs:

```
Running `"/home/wrzasa/.phantomjs/2.1.1/x86_64-linux/bin/phantomjs"  "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/jasmine-rails-0.14.6/lib/jasmine_rails/../assets/javascripts/jasmine-runner.js" "file:///tmp/js5/tmp/jasmine/runner.html?root=/tmp/js5&spec="`
Running: file:///tmp/js5/tmp/jasmine/runner.html?root=/tmp/js5&spec=
Starting...

Finished
-----------------
2 specs, 2 skipped or pending, 0 failures in 0.027s.

ConsoleReporter finished
```

But when I open http://localhost:3000/specs or open `tmp/jasmine/runner.html` in by browser it shows me `2 specs, 1 failure, 1 pending spec` with expected errors.

The minimal example reproducing the problem is [here on my github](https://github.com/wrzasa/jasmine-rails-not-working), feel free to use it if you want.

What's wrong with the `rake spec:javascripts` command? Where should I look for the reason for specs skipped by commandline?

Comment: OK, it was a bug in version 0.14.6 of jasmine-rails. Fixed very quickly in 0.14.7, but I had a bad luck to stumble this one ;-)